# Jquery Ajax Auto Refreshing <div>

Tags: html, ajax, django, jquery

Since I too have also seen this question on SO, so this might be a duplicate for many, but I've not found an answer to this question.

I want select an item from the navigation bar and show the content inside another  tag by replacing the current data with AJAX-generated data.

Currently I'm able to post the data into the python services, it processes it and finally returns it back to the client. This last part of changing the data into the `div` is not happening.

Here is my code.

**python service**

```
def dashboard(request):

    if request.is_ajax():
        which_nav_bar = request.POST['which_nav_bar']
        print which_nav_bar // prints which_nav_bar inside the terminal

    ctx = {'result' : "hellloooo"}
    return render_to_response('dashboard/dashboard1.html',ctx, context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

**JS file**

```
$(function (){
    $("#nav_bar li").click(function(){
        alert($(this).text());     // works fine
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //able to post the data behind the scenes
            url: "/dashboard/",
            data : { 'which_nav_bar' : $(this).text() },
            success: function(result){
                 $(".container-fluid").html(result);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar">
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                  <ul class="nav" id="nav_bar">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Device</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Content</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Help</li>
                </ul>
              </div>
        </div>  

<div class="container-fluid"></div>
```

**OUTPUT**

On `$(".container-fluid").html(result);` [this](http://www.flickr.com/photos/37280036@N04/9618885201/) is what I get actually. I instead want that my python code should return something(in this case `ctx`) and prints the ctx variable.

Answer (score 1):

change it id

```
<div id="container-fluid"></div>
```

this is id selector `$("#container-fluid")`

[id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

if you want to access by class you can use

`$(".container-fluid")`

[class-selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)

Comment: No. its correct. I'm actually browsing the navigation bar and so upon selecting an item from the navbar, it should populate the result inside the `<div id="container-fluid"></div>`, thats why the id-selector is `$("#nav_bar li")`.

Comment: @user1162512 i don't see a selector as $("#nav_bar li") in your js code

Comment: @user1162512 use `$("#container-fluid").html(result);`

Comment: Thanks Tushar. I was actually making a mistake with `.` and `#`. Thanks for your concern. But the data which is being shown inside the `<div id="container-fluid"></div>` is the complete HTML code. I want it to be "Helloooo". What blurp is it?

Comment: try $("#container-fluid").html(result);

Comment: @user1162512 you want result or text `I want it to be "Helloooo"`

Comment: Yes I want the text part.

Comment: try using `$("#container-fluid").html(result);` or use `$("#container-fluid").html("Helloooo");`

Comment: your second option will do it for sure(tried that already), but what if I want to send some data from backend and then display it onto the UI.

Comment: And first options shows the same HTML page again with a navigation bar inside the div again(ie now I have 2 nav-bars).

Comment: @user1162512 show me what `$("#container-fluid").html(result);` outputs and how you want to process it .

Comment: I have edited my question with the o/p. Kindly look into the same and provide your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$("#container-fluid").text(result);
```

to

```
$(".container-fluid").text(result);
```

`#` is used to access by `id` and `.` is used to access by `class`

Comment: The data which is being shown inside the div tag is the complete HTML code. I want it to be "Helloooo". What blurp is it?

Comment: try $("#container-fluid").html(result);

Comment: No. it renders the HTML code into HTML. I guess I'm not sending the correct data "Helllooo" in my python code. Can you please check is it correct or not?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$("#nav_bar li").click(function(){
        var text_input = $(this).text();     // works fine
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST", //able to post the data behind the scenes
            url: "/dashboard/",
            data : { 'which_nav_bar' : text_input  }
            success: function(result){
                $("#container-fluid").text(result);
            }

        });
    });
```

in your code you use

```
data : { 'which_nav_bar' : $(this).text()},
```

but in your ajax request `$(this).text()` would be undefined ,

so assign it to a variable and use it inside the `data{}`

and also remove the comma at the end

Comment: didnt worked. 2 things. First the selctor inside the success function should start with `.` and secondly in my ajax request `$(this).text()` is defined. I guess I'm not able to send the data back from my python code to the client-side properly.